# Error when using pandas read_excel: Hour must be in 0..23

Tags: python, excel, pandas, ods

I'm trying to read a few ODS-files using pandas, but I get the exception:
`Exception has occurred: ParserError x hour must be in 0..23: 128:45`

The reason is that I'm summing up worked hours inside the document, which gives me a value that is greater than 24h (in this case, 128:45). I don't even want to read that bit of the ODS, is there a way to get around the function calculating every value in the file? I've tried using nrows, skiprows, skipfooter etc...
Here's my minimal example (the problematic value is in row 36, 0-indexed, and not in column "F"):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./2021/10_october.ods', header=3, usecols="F", skipfooter=37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using panda datetime to convert the time in your excel sheet? That might be the cause of this problem. Not sure as I don't have access to your sample input file.
While doing that, you might want to "ignore" the errors:

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.to_datetime(dt, errors='ignore')
```

Comment: No, I think to use datetime you need to already have read the file right?  And that's what I'm struggling with...

Comment: I overlooked one thing in your question. You are opening an ODS file using pd.read_excel(). Since it's an open document spreadsheet, read_excel() might not be working well unless you use some kind of equivalent technique to open ODS (e.g. odfpy). 
Re: question, assuming the input file is being opened and read correctly, you should have a dataframe, which you will need to parse and transform to some representation which you can later transform to datetime object.

Comment: From what I understand, read_excel() uses odfpy in the background. Seems like odfpy just can't handle numbers in an HH:MM:SS format that are larger than 23:59:59 (there was some trick to getting it work in the ODS already). Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score -1):

My work-around for this was to just format the summed-up hours as a decimal number in the ODS. It's not as pretty as having the hours in a HH:MM:SS format, but good enough for my personal stuff. I couldn't find a way to get exactly what I want though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).